# Clear all fields in a form whenever hit back button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I used below code to reset all fields data whenever user hit back button.It is working perfectly on firefox but not in chrome.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('form').get(0).reset(); //clear form data on page load
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$(window).ready` function?

Comment: yup..I finally got the solution by using $('form').trigger("reset");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work on chrome

```
$('form').trigger("reset");
```

instead of

```
$('form').get(0).reset();
```

Comment: Working perfect..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTML DOM` form reset like this and call it when page is ready.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
```

Comment: That's the same than OP has, using jquery `.get()` you'll obtain the DOM object.